# Commit is not applied in android studio

Tags: android-studio, git-commit

i am working in the android project in which i always need to commit and push. but suddenly it is stopped working. when i click on commit button nothing is happen and commit process is not started. please help.
Thank you.

Comment: If you've installed `git` on your computer, try to do the same (commit, push) with command on terminal, or if you're on windows, just use git software https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: i always do it via GUI can you tell me how i can do it using console and where it is in studio. and commit is done in other project but the project in which i am working now is unable to commit.

Comment: Perhaps, try to re-clone your project ?